# Why are my accepted topics being deleted?

Tags: support, documentation

I wrote some topics for the documentation. They were accepted and are on the dashboard.

[image]

But today I have noticed a drop in reputation:

[image]

All three topics have been deleted, but I don't know why.

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/672/cherry-picking#t=201609281453499957341
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/355/rebasing#t=201609281453507734816
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/598/squashing#t=201609281453511268221

Comment: [Someone](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99438) submitted [changes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99437) to [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99436) them. Those changes were approved. Looks like the proposer felt the three examples did not belong where they were.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99438?filter-tags=git looks like someone was handling an improvement request.

Comment: @KevinB To be fair... They were handling _their own_ improvement requests. Seems they just really felt those examples didn't belong.

Comment: I don't disagree with the removal, given the reason.

Comment: @Kendra I actually at first issued IR's, when it dawn on me that I could do it myself.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't handle them... I mean, the author of a IR can't "handle" them.

Comment: well, you can't get credit for handling them as the author of the IR. :p

Comment: @Braiam I figured it was either that, or you issued them when you didn't have time to do it yourself and came back to see they hadn't been handled and took care of it from there.

Answer (score 9):

You can look at the history.

At the bottom of the page click on "edited yesterday", for example, and you get to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/revisions/672). You then can view all the edits.

Here's what I found for the reasons:

> [There's a tag for tortoise git, it doesn't belong here.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99438?filter-tags=git) - Braiam

> [This isn't even git](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99437?filter-tags=git) - Braiam

> [This is not git.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99436?filter-tags=git) - Braiam

Comment: Those reasons seems to be very [similar to those you type while submitting commits in git](https://xkcd.com/1296/)